# detecting which element was clicked before when i click an element

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on a slider using css and Jquery.
Now when I click  on a thumb the image fades in with Z index higher. Now i want the previous clicked 
image to be grabbed so that it can be given give the previous image a z index lower or something. 
Thanks.

Comment: Use a class to have the z-index changed. Then remove it from the old clicked image and add it to the newly clicked image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the previously clicked element in a variable :

```
var lastClicked = $([]);

$('.thumb').on('click', function() {
    lastClicked.css('z-index', 2);

    lastClicked = $(this).css('z-index', 3); // returns this
});
```

or target all other element but `this` :

```
$('.thumb').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css('z-index', 3);

    $('.thumb').not(this).css('z-index', 2);
});
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand, if i save lastClicked on a thumb click, won't it save the value of lastClicked to currentclicked value? Can you create a fiddle my man?